# Select case not working with Text gameObject in Unity comparing strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity where the user selects a phrase from a list and receives a point if the phrase is correct.

The problem i'm having is despite selecting the right answer, when the code arrives to a switch it's right case does not match.

```cs
switch (answer.text)
{            
    case "it's a potato":
    points++;
}
```

if I do a `Debub.log(answer.text);` I get `"it's a potato"`

it's like `answer.text` add some invisible extra character and do not match.

If I write the string manually then it works.

Can someone tell me what can I do with the string `answer.text` to match the case please?

Comment: Did you forget a _break_?

Comment: Try copy pasting the text from the debug log, also put a debug log in the default case to make sure the switch is even running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the string was being changed by adding a `"\r"` at its end.

The solution I used was simply by doing:

```
anser.text.replace("\r", string.empty);
```

It worked like a charm. Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Strings may be not equals if the end of first string is not equal \n. In this case you can try to check it, just to translating it to char array or byte array. And certainly don't forget to write break for any case.

Comment: If there is a hidden character missing them how would `translating it to char array or byte array` solve the issue? The character still won't be there ...